# An Indentity of Poisson process

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, poisson-process, renewal-processes

**Question:**

Suppose buses arrive at a bus stop according to a Poisson process $N_t$ with parameter
. Given a fixed $t > 0$. The time of the last bus before t is $S_{N_t}$ , and the time of the
next bus after $t$ is $S_{N_{t+1}}$. Show the following identity:$E(S_{N_{t+1}}-S_{N_t})=(2-e^{-\lambda t})/{\lambda}$.

**My attempt:**

One basic conclusion about Poisson proccess is that:
 the time interval between two arrivals follows $Expo(\lambda)$.

But here,as t is a fixed time point,it can be any point in the interval $S_{N_t}$ and  $S_{N_{t+1}}$.Thus I found it impossible to use the above assumption.So what should I do next?

Answer (score 2):

See my answer here for the derivation of the density of $L_t: = S_{N_{t+1}}-S_{N_t}$:

[Deriving the distribution of residual time in a Poisson process.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3507199/deriving-the-distribution-of-residual-time-in-a-poisson-process)

It follows that
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[L_t] &= \mathbb E[L_t\mathsf 1_{(0,t)}(x)] + \mathbb E[L_t\mathsf 1_{(t,\infty)}(x)]\\
&= \int_0^t \lambda^2  x^2 e^{-\lambda  x} \, dx + \int_t^{\infty } \lambda  x (\lambda  t+1) e^{-\lambda  x} \, dx\\
&= \frac1\lambda e^{-\lambda t} (-\lambda t) (\lambda  t+2)-2)+2\lambda + \frac1\lambda e^{-\lambda t} (\lambda  t+1)^2 \\
&=\frac{2-e^{-\lambda  t}}{\lambda }.
\end{align}